# Z3py: coercion and value extraction between Float32() and BitVecSort(32)

Tags: python, floating-point, z3, smt, z3py

I am currently experimenting with the floating point (FP) theory, in combination with bit-vectors; I am working with `Z3 4.6.0.0`.

I have found limited documentation in the use of the FP API (it seems the only real hits are on `z3.py` itself), so I have try to provide "complete" examples, to also act as a demonstration of how I (believe) the API should be used.

Here was my first attempt at using the FP theory inside of Z3py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from z3 import *

s = Solver()

#
# Create our value
#
to_find = "-12.345"
fp_val = FPVal(to_find, Float32())

#
# Create our variable
#
fp_var = Const("fp_var", Float32())

#
# Create the constraints
#
s.add(fp_var == fp_val)

assert s.check() == sat, "assertion never fails because the instance is SAT"

m = s.model()

#
# Prints -12.3449993134
#
print eval(str(m.eval(fp_var, model_completion=True)))

# EOF
```

If you run this example, it works as expected, and we indeed get that `fp_var` is equal to (I presume) the float nearest to `-12.345` (so far so good; apart from the use of Python's `eval` to obtain the value as a Python float).

My next step was to try and coerce a floating point value into a bit-vector, whilst checking a non-integer value:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from z3 import *

s = Solver()

#
# Create our value
#
to_find = "-12.345"
fp_val = FPVal(to_find, Float32())

#
# Create our variable
#
bv_var = Const("bv_var", BitVecSort(32))

#
# We now use a "cast" to allow us to do the floating point comparison
#
fp_var = fpSignedToFP(RNE(), bv_var, Float32())

#
# Create the constraints
#
s.add(fp_var == fp_val)

#
# This is UNSAT because fpSignedToFP only supports _integers_!
#
assert s.check() == unsat, "instance is UNSAT, so assertion doesn't fail"

# EOF
```

In this example, we attempt to "convert" from the bit-vector into a floating point value (using `fpSignedToFP`), and then assert that the floating point value is equal to the value we are looking for. However, and this matches the documentation for Z3, we get UNSAT, because `fpSignedToFP` only supports integers.

I then started to "get creative" and see if I could use transitivity with the `fpToSBV` API call, which *does not* state it has the limitation of being restricted to only integer floats:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from z3 import *

print get_full_version()

s = Solver()

#
# Create our value
#
to_find = "-12.345"
fp_val = FPVal(to_find, Float32())

#
# Create our variable
#
bv_var = Const("bv_var", BitVecSort(32))

#
# We now create an additional, ancillary variable
#
fp_var = Const("fp_var", Float32())

#
# Create the constraints
#
s.add(fp_var == fp_val)
s.add(bv_var == fpToSBV(RNE(), fp_var, BitVecSort(32)))

assert s.check() == sat, "this example works"

m = s.model()

#
# Prints -12.3449993134
#
print eval(str(m.eval(fp_var, model_completion=True)))

#
# To read out the value from the BV, we create a new variable, assert it is
# the same as the originating BV, and then extract our new variable
#
eval_fp = Const("eval_fp", Float32())
s.add(bv_var == fpToSBV(RNE(), eval_fp, BitVecSort(32)))

assert s.check() == sat, "this cannot change the satisfiability"

m = s.model()

#
# Prints +oo True True
#
print str(m.eval(eval_fp, model_completion=True)),
print m.eval(eval_fp, model_completion=True).isInf(),
print m.eval(eval_fp, model_completion=True).isPositive()

# EOF
```

To explain this example slightly: we encode our problem as normal, but rather than creating a term for our floating point expression, we create a whole new constant, and assert that our bit-vector is equal to the floating point value, via `fpToSBV`. Our assertion on the value we wish to find is then against our floating point value. If this model is satisfiable, we then create *another* floating point constant, that points to our original bit-vector and we try to extract the value for that constant.

This gives a chain like this:

- `bv_var` == `fpToSBV(fp_var)`
- `fp_var` == `-12.345`
- `fpToSBV(eval_fp)` == `bv_var`

which I had hoped by transitivity would have either given the same value for `fp_var` and `eval_fp`. However, while `fp_var` gets the correct value, `eval_fp` comes out as positive infinity!

I also tried experimenting with the use of `fpToSBV` and `fpSignedToFP` together to try and see if that would work (I was sceptical of this, due to the limitations in `fpSignedToFP`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from z3 import *

s = Solver()

#
# Create our value
#
to_find = "-12.345"
bv_val = fpToSBV(RNE(), FPVal(to_find, Float32()), BitVecSort(32))

#
# Create our variable
#
bv_var = Const("bv_var", BitVecSort(32))

#
# Create the constraints
#
s.add(bv_var == bv_val)

assert s.check() == sat, "this example works"

m = s.model()

#
# Floating point constant to evaluate
#
eval_fp = fpSignedToFP(RNE(), bv_var, Float32())

#
# Prints -12.0
#
print eval(str(m.eval(eval_fp, model_completion=True)))

# EOF
```

This had the most success and did actually give an integer *close* the the floating point value of our constraint (i.e., -12.0). However, it still does not contain the values after the decimal place.

So, my question is: in Z3, is it possible to coerce a floating point value into a bit-vector, and then "back out" again? If so, how should it be done? Alternatively, are the bit-vector/floating point operations only "partially interpreted" (like with int2bv and friends)?

**Update**

After experimenting some more, I found that the following works (using the Z3-specific extension `fpToIEEEBV`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from z3 import *

s = Solver()

#
# Create our value
#
to_find = "-12.345"
fp_val = FPVal(to_find, Float32())

#
# Create our variable
#
bv_var = Const("bv_var", BitVecSort(32))

#
# Convert the value to check to a BV
#
bv_val = fpToIEEEBV(fp_val)

#
# Create the constraints
#
s.add(bv_var == bv_val)

assert s.check() == sat, "this example is SAT, so don't see this"

m = s.model()

#
# Evaluation expression
#
eval_expr = fpBVToFP(bv_var, Float32())

#
# Prints -12.3449993134
#
print eval(str(m.eval(eval_expr)))

# EOF
```

Is this the correct way of dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside how the Python API works, this is already specified in the definition of the floating-point logic, see here: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FloatingPoint.shtml

In particular, note the partiality of some of these functions:

> "All fp.to_* functions are unspecified for NaN and infinity input
>   values.   In addition, fp.to_ubv and fp.to_sbv are unspecified for
>   finite number inputs   that are out of range (which includes all
>   negative numbers for fp.to_ubv).
>       This means for instance that the formula
>
> ```
> (= (fp.to_real (_ NaN 8 24)) (fp.to_real (fp c1 c2 c3)))
> ```
>
> is satisfiable in this theory for all binary constants c1, c2, and
>   c3   (of the proper sort).   "

So, what you're doing (pending Python specific aspects) is per the standard, with the above caveats.

## Using the interchange format

For conversions to/from IEEE754 interchange format, the logic provides a way to convert a given-bit vector to a corresponding float:

> ; from single bitstring representation in IEEE 754-2008 interchange
>   format,    ; with m = eb + sb    ((_ to_fp eb sb) (_ BitVec m) (_
>   FloatingPoint eb sb))

In the other direction, the logic has this to say:

> There is no function for converting from (_ FloatingPoint eb sb) to
>   the   corresponding IEEE 754-2008 binary format, as a bit vector (_
>   BitVec m) with    m = eb + sb, because (_ NaN eb sb) has multiple,
>   well-defined representations.   Instead, an encoding of the kind below
>   is recommended, where f is a term   of sort (_ FloatingPoint eb sb):
>
> (declare-fun b () (_ BitVec m))
>      (assert (= ((_ to_fp eb sb) b) f))

Again, all this is in http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FloatingPoint.shtml

Comment: Hi [@Levent Erkok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936310/levent-erkok) -- thanks for your comment! I think maybe I should reformulate my question. I want to go _from_ an FP, into a BV, and then _back out_ to an FP, preserving the original FP number -- is that possible? I did indeed refer to the FP logic definition, and it seems that functions such as `fp.to_ubv` to the conversion to the _nearest_ (as per the rounding mode) signed/unsigned value. What I really want is to pack the FP into a BV, precisely preserving the FP bit pattern, for later extraction.

Comment: @JędrekJażdżyk: No, it's not possible, because of the unspecified encoding of NaNs. The SMT standard does not provide an encoding for NaNs and instead suggests the use of `(assert (= ((_ to_fp eb sb) b) f))`. For convenience, Z3 offers `fpToIEEEBV`, but whatever results from that is unsound with respect to the SMT FP standard.